# Ignite throws SocketTimeoutException randomly while running in PROD

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

It throws below error and restarts thereafter without printing much logs.

```
TcpDiscoverySpi [tcp-disco-sock-reader-[]-#13-#76] Failed to initialize connection (this can happen due to short time network problems and can be ignored if does not affect node discovery) [sock=Socket[addr=/10.178.19.121,port=45450,localport=18036]]
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$SocketReader.body(ServerImpl.java:6784) ~[ignite-core-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58) ~[ignite-core-2.10.0.jar!/:2.10.0]
```

What could be the potential reason for this error and how to prevent Ignite from throwing this error?